# Need more context from this wikipedia statement about quaternion multiplication

Tags: quaternions

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Quaternions_and_the_geometry_of_%E2%84%9D3) in the wikipedia article on quaternions, the following is written:

> In general, let p and q be quaternions and write
> $${\displaystyle p=p_{\text{s}}+p_{\text{v}},}$$$$
> {\displaystyle q=q_{\text{s}}+q_{\text{v}},}$$
> where $p_\text{s}$ and $q_\text{s}$ are the scalar parts, and $p_\text{v}$ and $q_\text{v}$ are the vector parts of p and q. Then we have the formula $${\displaystyle pq=(pq)_{\text{s}}+(pq)_{\text{v}}=(p_{\text{s}}q_{\text{s}}-p_{\text{v}}\cdot q_{\text{v}})+(p_{\text{s}}q_{\text{v}}+q_{\text{s}}p_{\text{v}}+p_{\text{v}}\times q_{\text{v}}).}{\displaystyle pq=(pq)_{\text{s}}+(pq)_{\text{v}}=(p_{\text{s}}q_{\text{s}}-p_{\text{v}}\cdot q_{\text{v}})+(p_{\text{s}}q_{\text{v}}+q_{\text{s}}p_{\text{v}}+p_{\text{v}}\times q_{\text{v}}).}$$

Which I have no issue with. But then they go on to write:

> Hamilton showed that this product computes the third vertex of a spherical triangle from two given vertices and their associated arc-lengths, which is also an algebra of points in [Elliptic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_geometry).

For which I need more context to understand what it means. Are they saying that if $p_\text{v}$ and $q_\text{v}$ correspond to two vertices, then $(pq)_\text{v}$ is somewhat related to/corresponds to the third vertex? And *how exactly* are the arc-lengths included in this relation? The citation provided there is hard to comprehend for me, so I decided to ask here (I do not have any knowledge of quaternions prior to reading that much of the Wikipedia article). I am **not** asking for a proof, just want to know what the theorem is.

Comment: That assertion is already, one minute after you posted your question,  gone from the Wikipedia page, so it's hard to do much with it unless someone recognizes the claim and can guess the relevant reference and explain it for you.

Comment: This seems to be what you're referring to? Equation K is close to what you have in mind, perhaps not quite https://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Hamilton/Quatern1/Quatern1.html